# Grid+ing and labeling the 3d Points

Tags: python, 3d, quantization

I have matrix of 3D points. I want to quantize them into spatial grid and late represent that matrix by their grid number.
Let say the matrix is **D**

```
D = np.array([[-45.08341177,  34.40457052,   7.63253164],
       [-46.81391587,  34.35034554,   8.08080687],
       [-48.25988676,  34.29036266,   8.11271667],
       [-42.78217419,  24.51951629,   5.04130893],
       [-44.50295096,  25.34408096,   5.26748238],
       [-46.18559432,  25.60061165,   5.19218065]])
```

I take x, y, and z into arrays

```
x = D[:,0]
y = D[:,1]
z = D[:,2]
```

Now I find the limit of spatial grid

```
r = np.zeros(x.shape)
n = 25
xE =  np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), num = n+1 )
yE =  np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), num = n+1 )
zE =  np.linspace(np.min(z), np.max(z), num = n+1 )
```

on above code, n shows the grid size. In this case it is nxnxn as space is 3D.

Now I want to label each point. This is done in Matlab on [this link](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1639770-divide-the-3d-feature-space-into-grid-and-then-get-their-labels?s_tid=prof_contriblnk).

Only the code given below part is not getting into Python, if any expert may kindly help.

[Matlab version]

```
idx = 1;
for ii = 1:numel(xE)-1
    for jj = 1:numel(yE)-1
        for kk = 1:numel(zE)-1
            r(x>xE(ii) & x<=xE(ii+1)  & y>yE(jj) & y<=yE(jj+1) & z>zE(kk) & z<=zE(kk+1)) = idx;
            idx = idx + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a 3D histogram?

Comment: No. I want to quantize the points into grid and later represent those points by their grid number. 2D example is explained on this link, https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1639770-divide-the-3d-feature-space-into-grid-and-then-get-their-labels?s_tid=prof_contriblnk

Comment: I think I understand, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more clever way to do this, but this will get the job done.  It looks like you want to step through a 3D grid of bins and use the bin "number" as a label for any points that reside in that bin.

You can use `np.histogramdd` to get the edges for each axis.  Then iterate through each pair of edges to create a 3D bin, and check which points fall within that bin.  You can use `itertools.product` to walk through all combinations of edges.

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

D = np.array([[-45.08341177,  34.40457052,   7.63253164],
       [-46.81391587,  34.35034554,   8.08080687],
       [-48.25988676,  34.29036266,   8.11271667],
       [-42.78217419,  24.51951629,   5.04130893],
       [-44.50295096,  25.34408096,   5.26748238],
       [-46.18559432,  25.60061165,   5.19218065]])

r = np.zeros(len(D), dtype=np.int64)
n = 25

_, (x_edges, y_edges, z_edges) = np.histogramdd(D, bins=(n, n, n))
# to account for the last edge being exactly at the max, we add a buffer
x_edges[-1] *= 1.00001
y_edges[-1] *= 1.00001
z_edges[-1] *= 1.00001

x_pairs = zip(x_edges, x_edges[1:])
y_pairs = zip(y_edges, y_edges[1:])
z_pairs = zip(z_edges, z_edges[1:])
bin_edge_iter = product(x_pairs, y_pairs, z_pairs)

for label, ((x0, x1), (y0, y1), (z0, z1)) in enumerate(bin_edge_iter):
    ix = (
        (x0 <= D[:,0]) & (D[:,0] < x1) 
        & (y0 <= D[:,1]) & (D[:,1] < y1) 
        & (z0 <= D[:2]) & (D[:2] < z1)
    )
    r[ix] = label
```

You requested this as a function, but an object is more appropriate in this case.  We need to store the information about the bin edges.

```
class BinLabeller3D:
    """Fits bins to data and assigns new data points a label."""
    def __init__(self, num_bins: int) -> None:
        self.num_bins = num_bins
        self.x_edges = None
        self.y_edges = None
        self.z_edges = None
        self._fit = False

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        n = self.__class__.__name__
        return f'<{n} num_bins={self.num_bins} at 0x{id(self):x}>'

    def __call__(self, data) -> np.array:
        return self.predict(data)

    def fit(self, data: np.array):
        """Fits the (num_bins x num_bins x num_bins) bin edges to the data.
        
        args:
            data: (array-like) an N x 3 sized array
        """
        _, (x_edges, y_edges, z_edges) = np.histogramdd(
            data,
            bins=(self.num_bins, self.num_bins, self.num_bins)
        )

        # to account for the last edge being exactly at the max, we add a buffer
        self.x_edges = x_edges
        self.y_edges = y_edges
        self.z_edges = z_edges
        self.x_edges[-1] *= 1.00001
        self.y_edges[-1] *= 1.00001
        self.z_edges[-1] *= 1.00001
        self._fit = True
        return self

    def predict(self, data: np.array) -> np.array:
        """Predicts the label for a new data point.
        
        args:
            data: (array-like) and N x 3 sized array.
        returns:
            labels: (np.array) a 1D array of bin labels.  Points outside of
                the bin range are labelled as -1.
        """
        if not self._fit:
            raise ValueError('Model must be fit before making a prediction')
        data = np.array(data)

        # if a single point is passed, convert it to a 2D array.
        if data.ndim == 1:
            data = data.reshape(-1, len(data))
        
        # check the shape
        if data.shape[-1] != 3:
            raise ValueError('The dimension of `data` must be (..., 3), '
                f'got {data.shape}')

        x_pairs = zip(self.x_edges, self.x_edges[1:])
        y_pairs = zip(self.y_edges, self.y_edges[1:])
        z_pairs = zip(self.z_edges, self.z_edges[1:])
        bin_edge_iter = product(x_pairs, y_pairs, z_pairs)

        # set all labels to -1, which indicates and out-of-range bin
        labels = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=np.int64) - 1

        for label, ((x0, x1), (y0, y1), (z0, z1)) in enumerate(bin_edge_iter):
            ix = (
                (x0 <= D[:,0]) & (D[:,0] < x1) 
                & (y0 <= D[:,1]) & (D[:,1] < y1) 
                & (z0 <= D[:2]) & (D[:2] < z1)
            )
            labels[ix] = label
        return labels
```

You would use it like this:

```
bin_labeller = BinLabeller3D(25)
bin_labeller.fit(D)

new_points = np.array([
       [-47.26760012,  26.26654462,   8.84124020],
       [-43.21719762,  23.46974622,   7.16000541],
       [-44.10245666,  29.44169842,   6.18476654]
])

new_labels = bin_labeller(new_points)
```

Comment: Thank you. You got it right. I want to label each 3D point based on their bin number. Could you please take it little forward and make a function that then return the bin number of unseen 3D point?

Comment: I added a class that should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you James. There is one logical error. The predict only works if new pionts have same number instances as of D.

Comment: James, actually fit should be done on data as training, and later, we want to predict for unseen data. The training data has more than 100K instances. Could it be made some how very fast for unseen data, lets say speed of hashing ?